How can I write unit tests for a Python function that interacts with external APIs?
I have a function in Python that interacts with an external API to fetch user data. I want to write unit tests for this function but don’t want to actually call the external API during the tests. How can I mock the API call to test this function without hitting the real API?
th code :{
import requests
def get_user_data(user_id):
response = requests.get(f"https://api.example.com/users/{user_id}")
return response.json()}
I’m looking for a way to mock the API call so that I can test the function in isolation and control the data it returns for testing purposes.

You'd ... just mock it, literally (post the test, and I'll write the mock). However, I don't see any reason to mock requests.get in this function. It doesn't do anything but return the api response unaltered, so it makes more sense to just mock get_user_data instead.
